# Collabnet SVN EDGE console takes too much time in loading administration tab

Tags: svn, collabnet, subversion-edge

We've got a new collabnet svn edge server on CentOS 7. But at times it is taking too much time to load management console specially when clicking on Administration Tab or during login.

When check console logs I found error "`ERROR admin.PackagesUpdateJob  - The Packages Update Service has not been bootstraped`". which seems a update checking java file as per below link

https://github.com/marcellodesales/svnedge-console/blob/master/grails-app/jobs/com/collabnet/svnedge/admin/PackagesUpdateJob.groovy

`Software version of SVN: 5.2.4`